# Code with i+= in the loop is not working

Tags: java, operators, variable-assignment

I have the following piece of code called Code1.

http://pastebin.com/tc0Vd8xh

When I run this, the sketch does not work.

However when I replace `"i=+50"` for `"i = i + 50"` the code works.

My question is why the `"i=+50"` bit does not work?

As far as I know `"i=+50"` is proper Java and Processing is based on Java. 
I tried to Google about `"i=+50"` but Google does not process non-alphanumeric characters.

So I came here and I searched in previous questions before asking here. Anyone, any idea why `"i=+50"` does not work?

Comment: You could have search for "Java operators" which might have taken you to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Operators (That is assuming you know what an operator is)

Comment: You are right. :) Yes, I know what an operator is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using =+, which is not a java operator (or an operator in any other language I know of)

The proper syntax is:

```
i+=50
```

Comment: My bad! Thank you! :) I would have spotted this if Google allowed non-alphanumeric input. :(

Answer (score 1):

The statement `i=+50` is the assignment of positive 50 to `i`. That is why it compiles, but doesn't add 50 to `i` on each loop. As @RoelHarbers and @ByoTic mentioned, you actually want `i += 50`

Answer (score 0):

Because it's i+=50 and not i=+50.

Answer (score 0):

i =+ 50 is not going to do what you want, it is going to initialize i with 50. Instead, use i+=50, this going to add the 50 to whatever value that i holds.